# Creating a loop for list of different data frames

Tags: r

I have a data frame for multiple dates which includes registration names(reg)-factor with levels, values and dates

```
Reg    Values date
<fctr> <dbl>  <fctr>
1       7     2018-02-01
3       10    2018-02-01
5       15    2018-02-01
1       16    2018-02-01
1       12    2018-02-02
2       5     2018-02-02
3       6     2018-02-02
```

And I want to choose all values for 2 random levels for each date.

I made a list of data frames for each date

```
df_list <- split(df, as.factor(df$date))
```

make a function and use a lapply to loop over whole data frame

```
rando <- (function (x){
subset(x,reg %in% sample(levels(x$reg), 2, replace = TRUE))
}

Result <- lapply(df_list, rando)
```

It works, but choose random levels from all dates, not particular date. As a result, sometimes algorithm chooses levels of Reg, which is not represented in certain data frame.

Desirable result

```
Reg    Values date
<fctr> <dbl>  <fctr>
  1       7     2018-02-01
  5       15    2018-02-01
  1       16    2018-02-01
  2       5     2018-02-02
  3       6     2018-02-02
```

Can you explain, how to choose levels only inside each df from list?

Comment: Use `levels(factor(x$Reg))` in your rando function instead of `levels(x$Reg)`

Comment: It helps, thanks! It is strange for me, because I thought, that it is already factor variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `unique()` intstead of `levels(factor())`. Here are some options:

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[Reg %in% sample(unique(Reg), size = 2)], by = date]
```

Raw translation into `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  filter(Reg %in% sample(unique(Reg), size = 2))
```

And into your current workflow in `base R`:

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  lapply(df_list, function(X) X[X$Reg %in% sample(unique(X$Reg), size = 2), ])
)
```

Comment: Maybe I forgot to add `replace = TRUE`?